# Is there a standard content (mime) type I should be using for wiki formatted text files?

Tags: wiki, content-type, markdown, creole

I am taking user input as either wiki formatted text (creole) or possibly markdown formatted text.

I was wondering if there are there any existing content types standard for this sort of text.

I was hoping for something like "text/wiki_creole" or "text/markdown".

**EDIT**

Looks like there are no standards. The best I could find was

```
text/x-web-markdown
text/x-web-textile
```

which seem to be commonly used. Other than that it seems it is not unusual to use vendor specific types too, GitHub uses formats like

```
application/vnd.github-issue.raw+json
```

Comment: Answered here: [what-is-the-mime-type-for-markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701983/what-is-the-mime-type-for-markdown)

Comment: Be careful, for me "wiki format" is [wikicode](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Formatting), not markdown.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this (experimental) media/mime-type:

```
text/x-wiki.creole
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Wikimedia uses `text/x-wiki`, according to this API documentation:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=wbformatvalue