# What is the MIME type for Markdown?

Tags: mime-types, markdown, mime, plaintext

Does anyone know if there exists a MIME type for Markdown? I guess it is `text/plain`, but is there a more specific one?

Answer (score 176):

### tl;dr: `text/markdown` since March 2016

In March 2016, `text/markdown` was registered as [RFC7763 at IETF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763).

Previously, it should have been `text/x-markdown`. The text below describes the situation before March 2016, when RFC7763 was still a draft.

---

There is no official recommendation on [Gruber’s definition](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), but the topic was discussed quite heavily on the [official mailing-list](http://six.pairlist.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/2007-June/thread.html#640), and reached the choice of `text/x-markdown`.

This conclusion was [challenged later](http://six.pairlist.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/2008-February/000960.html), has been confirmed and can be, IMO, considered consensus.

This is the only logical conclusion in the lack of an official mime type: `text/` will provide proper default almost everywhere, `x-` because we're not using an official type, `markdown` and not `gruber.` or whatever because the type is now so common.

There are still [unknowns](http://six.pairlist.net/pipermail/markdown-discuss/2007-June/000652.html) regarding the different “flavors” of Markdown, though. I guess someone should register an official type, which is supposedly [easy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4288#section-3.4), but I doubt anyone dares do it beyond John Gruber, as he very recently [proved](http://blog.codinghorror.com/standard-markdown-is-now-common-markdown/) his attachment to Markdown.

There is a [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-appsawg-text-markdown/) on the IETF for `text/markdown`, but the contents do not seem to describe Markdown at all, so I wouldn't use it until it gets more complete.

Answer (score 137):

There is no *official* standard type, but `text/markdown` seems to be the most common *de facto* type.  Most browsers and other reasonably sophisticated clients will likely see the `text/` part and default to `text/plain` anyway, so there's not much difference.

One caveat, though: all types under the `text/` hiearchy default to *ISO-8859-1* for their character type in the relevant RFC standards.  Most of the world has since moved on to *UTF-8*.  So unless you're positive you won't be using any funny characters (or live in an old Windows world) you might want to specify it as follows:

```
text/markdown; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Would have been awesome if mail clients supported this and used the Daringfireball Markdown as the basis for it. Unfortunately, they do not. I'm not even aware if anyone has submitted it to the IETF as a draft RFC. I also researched Enriched Text MIME type, and found that this is no longer supported in many mail clients -- which now favor HTML Mail. Besides, [Enriched Text format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_text) never supported hyperlinks.

Comment: By "funny characters" you mean the characters the vast majority of the world uses to communicate on a daily basis.

Comment: Yes, exactly. There are a lot of funny characters in the world. I try to be one of them.

Comment: If you're implementing this yourself, you should use `text/markdown`: `x-` prefixes were deprecated by [RFC 6648 (Best Current Practice 178)](http://www.rfc-editor.org/bcp/bcp178.txt) in June 2012.

Comment: Stuart P. Bentley: Excellent.  Hooray for progress.  >8->

Comment: The "relevant RFC" seems to be RFC 1521. But at least there the default charset is defined as `us-ascii`, not `iso-8859-1`. See http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1521#section-7.1.1

Comment: Daniel: That's out of date. There have been numerous "relevant" RFCs since 1521, and they were in partial contradiction. [RFC 2046](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-4.1.2) says `The default character set, which must be assumed in the absence of a charset parameter, is US-ASCII.` But [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-3.7.1) said that for HTTP/1.1 headers: `When no explicit charset parameter is provided by the sender, media subtypes of the "text" type are defined to have a default charset value of "ISO-8859-1" when received via HTTP.` That's cleared up with 6648.

Comment: Note this answer still doesn't work for file uploads: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ5jz/  `<input id='file' accept='text/x-markdown, application/pdf' type='file'>`

Answer (score 13):

Looks like **text/markdown** is going to be the standard.

- http://www.iana.org/go/draft-ietf-appsawg-text-markdown
- https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

  Search for `markdown`.

Answer (score 12):

According to [RFC7763 “The text/markdown type”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7763) from 2016, the general MIME type is

```
text/markdown; charset=UTF-8
```

where the `charset` parameter is required but need not be `UTF-8`.

That RFC also specifies an optional `variant` parameter, and the Internet
Assigned Numbers Authority maintains a [registry of Markdown
Variants](https://www.iana.org/assignments/markdown-variants/markdown-variants.xhtml)
by which the specific variant of Markdown can be specified, e.g.,

```
text/markdown; charset=UTF-8; variant=Original
text/markdown; charset=UTF-8; variant=GFM
text/markdown; charset=UTF-8; variant=CommonMark
```

Some variants allow further parameters, as specified in
[RFC7764 “Guidance on Markdown”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7764),
e.g., you could add `extensions=-startnum` with the `pandoc` variant to specify a tweak to the dialect,
although I do not know how/whether pandoc might actually interpret that.

#### Why is the character set required?

[RFC2046 “MIME Part Two”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) from 1996
set US-ASCII as the default character set, but also said

> The specification for any future subtypes of "text" must specify
> whether or not they will also utilize a "charset" parameter, and may
> possibly restrict its values as well.

Then [RFC2616 “HTTP/1.1”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) from 1999
specified ISO-8859-1 as the default character set for `text/*` transported over
HTTP, and with the web becoming a dominant mode of communication,
this became the presumed default encoding for `text/*` media types.

Without an explicit character set or registered mime-type-specific default, `text/*` is considered to be
US-ASCII, unless said text is transported over HTTP in which case it is
considered to be ISO-8859-1.

[RFC 6657 “Update to MIME regarding "charset" Parameter Handling
in Textual Media Types”](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6657)
attempted to clarify this discrepancy
by requiring all new media type registrations
to explicitly specify how
to determine the character set,
preferably by including it in the payload as HTML allows with
`<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

The [`text/markdown`
registration](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/markdown)
specifies the `charset`  parameter as “Required.” Therefore using a content-type of
`text/markdown` is technically invalid, and the character set of such content may
legitimately be interpreted as any of undefined, invalid, US-ASCII,
ISO-8859-1, or the UTF-8 that in practice it will almost always be.

Comment: Now all you need to install is https://github.com/simov/markdown-viewer — w00t!

Answer (score 6):

Found this thread from 2008 : http://www.mail-archive.com/markdown-discuss@six.pairlist.net/msg00973.html

Seems like the mime type `text/vnd.daringfireball.markdown` should be registered by the author of Markdown, until then the Markdown mime type can be specified as `text/x-markdown`.