# HTML file input "accept" attribute cross-browser compatibility

Tags: html, file-upload, markdown, mime-types

The [file input `accept` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181214/file-input-accept-attribute-is-it-useful) works pretty well. However, there are some browser incompatibilities especially when you only want to select certain file types, i.e., [mimetypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type).

For example, if you want to only accept markdown and pdf files (see code below), webkit browsers
allow one to select pdfs but ignore [any markdown mimetype I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701983/what-is-the-mime-type-for-markdown). Whereas Firefox ignores both mimetypes and allows you to select any file type.

Does anyone know how to get webkit browsers to accept markdown files?

http://jsfiddle.net/JZ5jz/

```
<label for='file'>upload</label>

<input id='file' accept='application/pdf, text/x-markdown' multiple='multiple' type='file'>
```

Comment: Did you try changing the order? Is webkit simply taking only the first accept value?

Comment: just tried changing the order, that doesn't matter, it will take a comma delineated list for most mimetypes, e.g., `application/pdf, application/msword`

Answer (score 2):

Now you can simply use .md to filter the markdown file

```html
<label for='file'>upload</label>

<input id='file' accept='.md' multiple='multiple' type='file'>
```