# Can Laravel validate markdown mime types?

Tags: laravel, markdown, mime-types, laravel-5.3, laravel-spark

Trying to validate a file upload to make sure it is a .md / markdown file.

I have this:

```
 'mdfile' => 'mimes:text/markdown'
```

But also tried many variations:

```
'mdfile' => 'mimes:markdown'
'mdfile' => 'mimes:md'
```

But it always fails even if I am uploading a markdown file.

Cannot find much information online about validating against markdown files, any help?

Answer (score 1):

There's no **official** mime type for markdown.

Try `text/x-markdown`. Or anything that "prefixes" with `text/*`.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25812177/4273867). Give a try on  **text/markdown**